# Remote web access to network

Tags: active-directory, ssl, ldap, remote-access

My company does presently use SSLExplorer top give customers access to terminal servers and other network resources. As 3sp closed down the source and sold out to Barracuda there are no more updates for this software.

- What alternatives are there to SSLExplorer besides the Barracuda Appliance and the Adito fork of SSLExplorer ? (With AD integration)
- Have anyone used Adito in a production enviroment, and what are the experience?
- How does the barracuda appliance compare to the SSLExplorer

Regards 
John

Comment: Just to clear up, you're looking for a more controlled SSL-VPN solution, as opposed to generic VPN suggestions?  If so, a title edit may help narrow your responses (e.g. clientless, or limited-access).

Comment: The SSLExplorer is getting outdated, as 3SP just closed the source and sold it to barracuda, that uses it in its appliance.
OpenVPN is now going to incorporate Adito as OpenVPN ALS, but it will take some time imo to get it up to standards.

The primary goal is so safely and easily get our customers to access the internal Terminal Servers. (Aswell as cheap to us.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cisco ASAs can have a VPN terminate on them, provided they aren't in transparent mode.  In addition to that, because of the functionality you get with the ASAs, I highly recommend them.  VPN is relatively easy to set up using the ASDM (gui) and no longer has to be accomplished from the CLI.  In fact, there is some functionality that can't be set up from the CLI.

EasyVPN, WebVPN, the AnyConnect client, Digital Certs, Radius, TACACS, VPN policies, Split Tunneling, Hairpinning...IMHO Cisco does VPN right.

The entry level ASA, 5505, is also relatively inexpensive, around $600 if I remember correctly.

Comment: That would make sense if he was asking for something that is primarily a firewall.  From what I gathered all he is looking for is an SSL VPN replacement, not even anything for IPSEC.  It will also be more than 600 to get user access licenses.

Comment: The ASAs replace their VPN concentrators

Comment: this is a solution that would work, depending upon money and ease of use.

Answer (score 1):

There are commercial versions like [Juniper's Secure Access (formerly Neoteris)](http://www.juniper.net/us/en/products-services/security/sa-series/) which in my opinion is the best of the SSL VPN appliances.  Cisco offers SSL VPN functionality in their ASA, and Watchguard sells an appliance as well. Depending on your needs the Juniper SA 700 will support up to 25 users.  If you have more concurrent users, you'll need to look at the SA 2000 which supports 100.

If it isn't a project worth any money to your company I'd say [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/) is the only other big open source SSL VPN option.

Comment: this is a solution that would work, depending upon money and ease of use.